# Decision boundary for logistic loss and soft 0-1 loss

Tags: regression, logistic, loss-functions

I have a problem at hand that I have the solution to, but I quite can't make sense of the solution. Any help is appreciated.

We are given the data set in the below figure. [image: figure 1]

We are asked to plot the decision boundaries for the following models:

- A generative model with Gaussian class conditionals where each class has its own mean and spherical covariance matrix,
- A logistic regression model,
- A linear model trained with soft zero-one loss.

And here is the answer:

[image: figure2]

I understand the boundary for the Gaussian model but I am lost on the logistic regression and the soft 0-1 loss one. Why is the logistic regression one going through the origin? Is the soft 0-1 loss like an SVM classifier? I guess that would make the dashed line the middle of the possible maximum margin solution. Any insight is appreciated. How can I decide on a decision boundary for losses if I am just given data?

Comment: Is the logistic reg one actually going through the origin, or just close?  And what is meant by a decision boundary, a boundary where the prediction is 0.5?  If the logistic reg model doesn't have a bias / intercept term, then there will necessarily be a line through the origin where the prediction is 0.5.

Comment: @MathFoliage no the question doesn't say anything about the bias. So it could very well be just really close to the origin and not exactly through the origin. And yes I think the decision boundary is where the prediction is 0.5. The question, again, doesn't state that but I don't see any other way around